# Describe all martingales that only take values ​in $\{−1, 0, 1\}$.

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-expectation, martingales

> Describe all martingales that only take values ​​in $\{−1, 0, 1\}=:\Omega$.

In the first instance i would try to find a filtration of

$$P(\Omega)=\{\emptyset,\{0\},\{1\},\{-1\},\{1,-1\},\{1,0\},\{-1,0\},\Omega\}.$$

Candidates are:

- $P(\emptyset),P(\{0\}),P(\{1\})\subseteq P(\{0,1\})\subseteq P(\Omega)$
- $P(\emptyset),P(\{0\}),P(\{-1\})\subseteq P(\{0,-1\})\subseteq P(\Omega)$
- $P(\emptyset),P(\{0\}),P(\{1\})\subseteq P(\{0,1\})\subseteq P(\Omega)$
- $P(\emptyset),P(\{1\}),P(\{-1\})\subseteq P(\{1,-1\})\subseteq P(\Omega)$

I'm not really sure how to proceed. Any assistance or thoughts would be much appreciated.

Comment: I'm confused.  Are the values to be taken by the martingale elements of  $\{-1,0,1\}$, or is the sample space to be $\{-1,0,1\}$?

Comment: @JohnDawkins: I also racked my head about how to interpret the question correctly. The longer i think about it, the more i come to the conclusion, that the question was asked in a wrong manner due to translationproblems. Correctly it should be formulated as follows "Describe all Martingale $(X_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ such that $X_n\in\{-1,0,1\}$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: This seems to be a more interesting question. More difficult too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any martingale taking values in $\lbrace -1,0,1\rbrace$ has the form $X_n = E[X_\infty|\mathcal{F}_n]$ for some $\lbrace -1,0,1\rbrace$-valued random variable $X_\infty$ and some filtration $(\mathcal{F}_n)$. This is because any such martingale is bounded hence by the martingale convergence theorem it converges a.s. and in $L^1$ to some $X_\infty$ and $X_n = E[X_\infty|\mathcal{F}_n]$. ($X_\infty$ necessarily takes values in $\lbrace -1,0,1\rbrace$ by a.s. convergence). Furthermore, since there are finitely many sub-$\sigma$-fields in $\mathcal{P}(\Omega)$, the filtration has to be stationary, i.e. there exists $\mathcal{F} \subset \Omega$ such that $\mathcal{F}_n = \mathcal{F}$ for $n$ large enough.

**In conclusion**, every martingale taking values in $\lbrace -1,0,1\rbrace$ is stationary, in the sense that there exists a (nonrandom) integer $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that
$$X_n = E[X_\infty|\mathcal{F}_n], \quad \forall n \leqslant N,$$
and
$$X_n = X_\infty, \quad \forall n >N,$$
where $X_\infty$ is some $\lbrace -1,0,1\rbrace$-valued random variable and $\mathcal{F}_1, \ldots, \mathcal{F}_N$ is a (finite) filtration.

Comment: Can you explain why there are just finitely many sub-$\sigma$-fields in $\mathcal{P}(\Omega)$? Do you assume $|\Omega|<\infty$?

Comment: Yes because $\Omega = \lbrace -1,0,1\rbrace$. @n3ckbeard-wizzard

Comment: What if we assume $\Omega$ as arbitrary samplespace an $X_n\in\{-1,0,1\}$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$? Then we can not allways find a stationary filtration $(\mathcal{F}_n)$, therefore $X_n$ does not necessarily have to be stationary.

Comment: Sorry I got confused with the notation. In case of an arbitrary sample space, the first part remains true so the martingale will be of the form $E[X_\infty|\mathcal{F}_n]$. I'm not sure if we can say more.