# Describe all martingales $(X_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$, such that $X_n\in\{-1,0,1\}$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ with an arbitrary sample space $\Omega$.

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, conditional-expectation, martingales, filtrations

> Describe all martingales $(X_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$, such that $X_n\in\{-1,0,1\}$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ with an arbitrary sample space $\Omega$.

This Question evolved out of [this Question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3703891/describe-all-martingales-that-only-take-values-in-%E2%88%921-0-1?noredirect=1&lq=1) where $\Omega$ is **not** arbitrary. I racked my head about how to approach this Problem. A hint was to look at $\mathbb{P}(X_{n+k}=X_k|X_n=1)=\dots$. But this does not get me any further.

Any assistance or thoughts would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you prove $\mathbb{P}(X_{n+1}=1|X_n=1)=1$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $(X_n)$ be a Martingal that meets the above conditions.
Then the following properties apply:

*Claim 1:* $\mathbb{P}(X_{n+k}=X_n\forall k\in\mathbb{N}|X_n=1)=1$

> Assume $\mathbb{P}(X_{n+1}\neq X_n|X_n=1)>0$. Then for all $\omega\in\{X_n=1\}$ the following inequality holds: $$E[X_{n+1}|\mathcal{F}_n]=\mathbb{P}(X_{n+1}=X_n|X_n=1)-\mathbb{P}(X_{n+1}=-1|X_n=1)<1=X_n$$ With induction this can be shown for all $k\in\mathbb{N}$. Which makes the sequence $(X_n)$ not a martingale.

*Claim 2:* $\mathbb{P}(X_{n+k}=X_n\forall k\in\mathbb{N}|X_n=-1)=1$

> can be proven analogously to claim 1.

*Claim 3:* Let $T:=\min\{n\in\mathbb{N}_0\cup\{\infty\}|X_n\in\{-1,1\}\}$. Then:
$$\forall x<T:X_n=0 \text{ (a.s) }\wedge \forall n\geq T:X_n=X_T\text{ (a.s) }$$

> The first property follows from the construction of $T$ itself.  So let $\mathbb{P}(X_n\neq X_T)>0$ for a particular $n>T$.
> Then either Claim 1 or Claim 2 does not apply. Which proves the second property.

So $(T,X_T)$ describes the searched Martingale. The only restriction on the distribution of this random vector in $(\mathbb{N}_0\cup\{\infty\})\times\{-1,1\}$ is the following:

*Claim 4:*$\forall n\in\mathbb{N}: \mathbb{P}(X_T=1,T=n)=\mathbb{P}(X_T=-1,T=n)=\frac{1}{2}$

> First of all we note that $E[X_{n+1}|\mathcal{F_n}]=0$ holds in $\{X_n=0\}$.Furthermore, it also applies that:
> $$E[X_{n+1}|\mathcal{F_n}]=\mathbb{P}(T=n+1,X_{n+1}=1)-\mathbb{P}(T=n+1,X_{n+1}=-1)$$
> With which the claim follows.

The last point that still has to be proven is that such a sequence always forms a martingale.

> Let $(T,X_T)$ be an arbitrary random vector which suffices claim 4. Then the sequence $(X_n)$ is integrable (because it is bounded) and is adapted (because $T$ is a stopping time). Further $E[X_{n+1}|\mathcal{F}_n]=X_n$ applies because $X_{n+1}=X_n=X_T$ (a.s) holds in $\{T\leq n\}$ by Definition, such that $E[X_{n+1}|\mathcal{F}_n]=X_T=X_n$. In $\{T=n+1\}$ claim 4 holds, such that $E[X_{n+1}|\mathcal{F}_n]=0=X_n$. Moreover $X_{n+1}=X_n=0$ (a.s.) holds in $\{T>n+1\}$, such that $E[X_{n+1}|\mathcal{F}_n]=0=X_n$.